# React-redux: How to persist user across multiple tabs?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jwt, persistence

I am working on a react-redux web app, and it uses JWT tokens to authenticate the user. This token is stored in the redux store and accessed whenever I need to provide auth token in an XHR request, until here is standard practice, I guess. What I wanna know is when I open a new tab and visit my app, or when I open a link on my page in a new tab by right-clicking on it I am again redirected to the login page on the new tab, as the login does not persist, even though I am logged into one of the tabs, I would like to know, how to persist the user across tabs, like most websites, do nowadays.
Thank you in advance, if you think the question needs more clarification or code snippets, or any such thing, please let me know, and NO I am not looking for ready-made code, I would even be happy to know the theoretical way for implementing this.

Comment: You should  add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your keyboard has a ⏎ (return) key, if you use that then blocks of texts you write will be easier to read. If you store the key in local storage then it will be available in all tabs and windows (not anonymous or other user profile). [Redux persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) can be used to store (part) of the redux store in session or local storage, there are other storage methods but I think these will provide the solution for you. You could also check localStorage when initializing state.

Comment: localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
            return user;
  });